# c++.net Winform function cannot be destinguished even though it has a unique name

Tags: winforms, visual-c++, overloading, return-type

I am writing a simulation with a winform user interface in C++.
To pass information to the user interface, I intend to use a structure that is passed as a function.

I have multiple files that are all included in the build. Relevant code is included below. For it to run without errors, 2 lines need to be removed.

The first file is holds structure definitions.

```
//Structures.h

#pragma once
struct userOutput {

   double x;
   double y;

};
```

second Mylib.h with all declarations:

```
//Mylib.h

#include <stdio.h>
#include <msclr\marshal_cppstd.h>

#include "Structures.h"    

using namespace std;
using namespace System;
using namespace System::Windows::Forms;

//remove this line to build without errors.
userOutput function_with_a_unique_name(void);
```

File with code bodies:

```
//Pass_functions.cpp

#include "Mylib.h"

userOutput function_with_a_unique_name(void) {

    userOutput myOutput;

    return myOutput;
}
```

Main script:

```
//MyForm.cpp
#include "MyForm.h"

void main(void) {
    Application::EnableVisualStyles();
    Application::SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
    AluminiumCVD::MyForm form;
    Application::Run(% form);
    string user_end;
}
```

And the form itself:

```
#pragma once

#include "Mylib.h"

namespace AluminiumCVD {

    using namespace System;
    using namespace System::ComponentModel;
    using namespace System::Collections;
    using namespace System::Windows::Forms;
    using namespace System::Data;
    using namespace System::Drawing;

    /// <summary>
    /// Summary for MyForm
    /// </summary>
    public ref class MyForm : public System::Windows::Forms::Form
    {
    public:
        MyForm(void)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            //
            //TODO: Add the constructor code here
            //
        }

    protected:
        /// <summary>
        /// Clean up any resources being used.
        /// </summary>
        ~MyForm()
        {
            if (components)
            {
                delete components;
            }
        }

    protected:

private: System::Windows::Forms::Button^ button1;

    protected:

    private:
        /// <summary>
        /// Required designer variable.
        /// </summary>
        System::ComponentModel::Container^ components;

#pragma region Windows Form Designer generated code
        /// <summary>
        /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
        /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
        /// </summary>
        void InitializeComponent(void)
        {
            this->button1 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Button());
            this->SuspendLayout();
            // 
            // button1
            // 
            this->button1->Location = System::Drawing::Point(30, 38);
            this->button1->Margin = System::Windows::Forms::Padding(6, 6, 6, 6);
            this->button1->Name = L"button1";
            this->button1->Size = System::Drawing::Size(150, 44);
            this->button1->TabIndex = 135;
            this->button1->Text = L"button1";
            this->button1->UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            this->button1->Click += gcnew System::EventHandler(this, &MyForm::button1_Click);
            // 
            // MyForm
            // 
            this->AutoScaleDimensions = System::Drawing::SizeF(12, 25);
            this->AutoScaleMode = System::Windows::Forms::AutoScaleMode::Font;
            this->AutoSize = true;
            this->ClientSize = System::Drawing::Size(461, 366);
            this->Controls->Add(this->button1);
            this->Margin = System::Windows::Forms::Padding(6, 6, 6, 6);
            this->Name = L"MyForm";
            this->Text = L"Coating Simulation";
            this->Load += gcnew System::EventHandler(this, &MyForm::MyForm_Load);
            this->ResumeLayout(false);

        }


#pragma endregion
    private: System::Void MyForm_Load(System::Object^ sender, System::EventArgs^ e) {
    }
    
private: System::Void button1_Click(System::Object^ sender, System::EventArgs^ e) {

    //remove this line to build without errors
    userOutput myOutput = function_with_a_unique_name();
}

};

}
```

Before I add the function declaration to the Mylib.h file, the call in the winform is obviously unable to use the function. But when I add it, it gives the error:

cannot overload functions distinguished by return type alone.

And in the winform:

no suitable user-defined conversion from "UserInput" to "UserInput" exists.

I first tried to pass the pointer of the structure instead of the structure, but obtained similar issues.
Other functions that return the standard types have worked this exact way.

I am most surprised by the overload functions error, as there is only one function with this name. And from what I understand that should resolve the error.
For the conversion error I am not sure if there is a real issue, or if that gets resolved when the first error gets resolved.

Is there a way to return structures in this way? If so, can someone point me in the right direction.

Thanks in advance.

edit 1: Made changes to the code to get a minimal reproducable example.

edit 2: I made a mistake in creating this code without all the bagage of my real code.
What is now listed should work without errors. It seems there is mistake somewhere else in my code which I currently can't reproduce. Thanks for the comments and I will need to further investigate where the exact issue is.

Comment: this is not c++. I suppose it is c++-cli and tagged accordingly, if not please fix the tags

Comment: In C++ (and still not in C++/CLI) you don't need `typedef` for structures.

Comment: I dont know what it is, but it looks like it has a lot of typos (missing `;` and similar). Please read about [mcve] and try to provide one

Comment: And neither in C++ nor C++/CLI a construct like `Output = function_with_a_unique_name(void){ ... }` is valid. Please create a proper [mre] to show us.

Comment: I am not sure about the technical language, but Visual Studio says this is C++ in a .net framework.
I know typedef is not needed, but I find it more clear.

With the Winform it will be quite a bit of code to get something that runs. I will see if I can update it to something that is useable.

Comment: And if you get build errors or warnings, then please not only add a [mre], but also include the full and complete build log in your question, copy-pasted as plain text. Add comments in the code where you get the errors or warnings.

Comment: What *is* the type `UserInput`? Where is it defined? And considering your `userOutput`, are you sure it's not really supposed to be `userInput`, with a lover-case `u`? C++ (and all its variants) is case-sensitive. You have added more, but it's still not a [mre]. It's not something we can simply copy-paste and get the exact same error you get.

Comment: In my reconstruction I have accidentally changed Input and Output. (In my final script I wanted to pass both with this method). In this example they all should be type userOutput. Now it runs and doesn't return the errors of the initial script. I am going to look into what is different from the script.
I don't know what more is required for a minimal reproducible example. This is all the scripts I have loaded into visual studio.
Of course it now isn't reproducing the error anymore, so it is a moot point anyway. Excuses for this.